# Karaf cluster synchronization

Tags: apache-camel, esb, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have some misunderstandings about Karaf cluster Cellar replication.

We have 4 nodes, and all these nodes surrounding in the cluster.

First problem: 
If we install feature in cluster (cluster:feature install) and execute command cluster:bundle-list default, we see that all bundles in this feature have local type in column Located, but the feature has cluster/local type. 
How can I achieve that bundles have cluster/local type?

Second problem: 
When we install feature in cluster (cluster:feature install) all bundles exist in all nodes (auto sync) but then when we synchronize manually (cluster:sync -g default) for example on 3 nodes we see that bundles does not exist on it any more. 
To return feature bundles to 3 nodes we have to uninstall and install feature in cluster again.

Please comment this strange behaviour.

Version: 
apache-servicemix-7.0.1 
karaf 4.0.9 
cellar 4.0.4 
camel 2.16.5 
CXF 3.1.9

Comment: Do you able to solve this problem as i am facing it too?

Comment: no, unfortunately